# Subspace of $C^3$ that spanned by a set over C and over R

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis

Given $A=$ $\left\{ {(1,2 + i,i),(1,3 + i,3 - i),(i,3i,4 + i)} \right\}$

Let $SP_CA$ be the linear space spanned by A over $C$

Let $SP_RA$ be the linear space spanned by A over $R$

what is the dimension of each subspace ?

I did row operations on A and saw that A is linearly dependet.

and that $dim(SP_CA)=2$

But over $R$. I cannot do row operations with the scalar $i$ since its not belong to $R$
so what is $dim(SP_RA)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\det (A)=4(4-i)\neq 0$, all three row vectors are linearly independent over $\mathbb{C}$, hence also over $\mathbb{R}$ by the definition of linear independence.

Edit: The new matrix $A$ now is indeed singular and we have $\dim_{\mathbb{C}} (S)=2$. Now solve $\lambda_1v_1+\lambda_1v_1+\lambda_1v_1=0$ for real $\lambda$, to see that $\dim_{\mathbb{R}} (S)=3$.

Comment: I did row operations. they linearly dependet

Comment: No, they are not linearly dependent. What is your linear relation ?

Comment: I checked and calculate at two websites. they did row reduction for me. the third vector is dependet

Comment: Then express the third vector by the other two, so that we can check.

Comment: ok. I will check again maybe I entered wrong values since you are sure. one moment

Comment: I'm sorry. I edited the values.  its 1 instead of i at the second vecor